# Which type of token does Firebase Authentication use?

Tags: firebase, authentication

I'm a little bit confused about the token that Firebase Authentication provides for a user when a user succesfully have been created. The tokens is seen here in the userID column:
[image]

I'm not sure what the right term for it is. Is it a JWT token, an ID token or something else?

Comment: Those are the users' UIDs and not any tokens. They are just an identifier. For auth, Firebase uses JWTs. You can see them when you log in the user with Firebase SDK .

Comment: Yep, u right, found the tokens, thanks!